# UICollectionView Image Constraints Problem

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting crazy about this problem! I have a programmatically UICollectionView which are reused with images. The only problem is the size of the images, my images should be as big as the custom cells. And I can't seem to figure out why my images are smaller! Where do I go wrong?

Here is the code of the current Subview:

```
        
        addSubview(centerImageView)
        centerImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = false
        centerImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = false
        centerImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        centerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Comment: Maybe this : `centerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)` in the `CustomCell `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add constraints like this and set img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill like this:

```
contentView.addSubview(centerImageView)
centerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
centerImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
centerImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
centerImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: Adding a subview directly to the cell, and pinning the image view to the cell, is wrong.

Comment: @matt Hi Mat, exscuse me, I add the image of the result... Please can you explain me why it's wrong?...

Comment: There is nothing to explain. Telling the OP that code like `addSubview(centerImageView)` is okay is wrong. You are adding a view directly to the cell. You must not do that.

Comment: No, the constraints are still to the cell.

Comment: @Fabio & matt _Thanks! I got it all working now and the layout is now compatible with all different iPhones! Really appriciate it the help!

Comment: @DeDeSchurk have a nice day :)

Comment: @Fabio , thanks for answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934268/can-i-add-an-action-to-a-customcell-in-a-uicollectionview . You deleted the anwer but it works (I was fast enough), still looking for a solution to send the if tag0 is tapped sound0 is played. And when tag1 is tapped sound1 is played. But thank you so far, and sorry for my stupid questions. Viva Italia! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the main issue is:

   ```
   centerImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = false
   centerImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = false
   ```

   Please change it to `true`.
   In your code, you set the imageview's size explicitly (100x100). so in this case, you don't have to use constraints.

   You may create the imageview with frame like `centerImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))`. and remove the `img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
2. UIView's contentMode is `UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill` by default. so it's currently okay.
3. You should add the `subviews` to the `contentView` of `UICollectionViewCell`.
   like `self.contentView.addSubview(centerImageView)`

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue cause, you set image fixed width and height, green colour is your cell frame size.

So for your requirement fulfil need to set image frame full of the cell frame size, So set image constraint top, bottom, leading and trailing

```
centerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 0).isActive = true
centerImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 0).isActive = true
centerImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 0).isActive = true
centerImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 0).isActive = true
```