# Can I add an action to a customCell in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

First I had a couple of UIButtons with a @IBAction to play a sound when tapped. Because I had some problems with constraints on different iPhones I decided to go for a UICollectionView with CustomCells. Now I got this working I want to setup the CustomCells to play a sound when tapped. So I think I will have to setup something like an 'Action' on the custom cells for playing a sound. I do have a 'sort of action' that prints out that the user tapped a custom cell like;

`print("tapped tag > ", self.tag)`

The original @IBAction I used on a UIButton was:

```
@IBAction func sound2(_ sender: UIButton) {
sound2.play()
```

Again, I 'think' I need to setup a sort of action to the CustomCell for playing a sound?
And I 'think' I need to declare somewhere what sound to play along with the self.tag?
So each customCell will play a different sound..

The only problem, (rookieAlert) I don't know where to start :(
But I want to learn!
Can somebody point me into the right direction or provide me with some information?

Here is the full code of the project to make things more clear:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var countries = [UIImage(named:"c1"),UIImage(named:"c2"),UIImage(named:"c3"),UIImage(named:"c4"),UIImage(named:"c5"),UIImage(named:"c6"),UIImage(named:"c7"),UIImage(named:"c8"),UIImage(named:"c9"),UIImage(named:"c10")]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var soundsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    lazy var cv: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        
    var cc = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cc.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    cc.delegate = self
    cc.dataSource = self
    cc.backgroundColor = .black
    return cc
    }()
    
    let sounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4", "sound5"]
    
    var sound1 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var sound2 = AVAudioPlayer()
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            
            view.addSubview(cv)
            cv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            cv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            cv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            cv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            
            // Setting up sound1
            do {
                sound1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")!))
                sound1.prepareToPlay()
            } catch  {
                print(error)
            }
            
            // Setting up sound2
            do {
                sound2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound2", ofType: "mp3")!))
                sound2.prepareToPlay()
            } catch  {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
    
    @IBAction func sound2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sound2.isPlaying {
            sound2.stop()
            sound1.stop()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "sound1_off.jpg"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            sound2.play()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "sound1_on.jpg"), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.centerImageView.image = countries[indexPath.row]
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    }
    
    //define constant value as per your requirement and declare this variables globally
    let inset: CGFloat = 10 //define as per your requirement
    let minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 10 //define as per your requirement
    let cellsPerRow = 3

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            
       let marginsAndInsets = inset * 2 + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
            
       let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
       
       return .init(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
            
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    lazy var centerImageView: UIImageView = {
        var img = UIImageView()
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handler(_:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        return img
    }()
    
    @objc private func handler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("tapped tag > ", self.tag)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(centerImageView)
        centerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        

    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456441/how-to-add-uibutton-action-in-a-collection-view-cell

Comment: I delete my answer because it don't satisfy your question completely :)

Comment: Well, it did point me a little further in the right direction! :)

Comment: @DeDeSchurk I update my answer, there're 3 cases: one for the same sound in all cell, one for different sound and one for different system sound... here you can see a list of system sounds code: https://nikaeblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/11/system-sound-id-list-ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for same sound in all cell: try to delete gesture from your centerImage in custom cell, after that add the gesture in cellForItemAt and call the function like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
cell.centerImageView.image = countries[indexPath.row]
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playCellSound))
cell.centerImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    
 return cell
}
```

after that write the func below cellForItemAt:

```
@objc func playCellSound() {
    sound2.play()
    print("play sound...")
}
```

**FOR DIFFERENT SOUND IN CELLS:**

the number of sounds must be equal the number of countries:

```
let sounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4", "sound5", "sound6", "sound7", "sound8", "sound9", "sound10"]
```

after that declare your sounds like this:

```
var sound1 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound3 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound4 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound5 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound6 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound7 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound8 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound9 = AVAudioPlayer()
var sound10 = AVAudioPlayer()
```

set the other sound like sound 1 and sound 2

now this is your cellForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
 cell.centerImageView.image = countries[indexPath.row]
 cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    
 return cell
}
```

set numberOfItemsInSection like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countries.count // dynamic number of items based on your countries array
}
```

implement the method didiSelectItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let s = sounds[indexPath.item]
    switch s {
    case "sound1":
        sound1.play()
        print("s1")
    case "sound2":
        sound2.play()
        print("s2")
    case "sound3":
        sound3.play()
        print("s3")
    case "sound4":
        sound4.play()
        print("s4")
    case "sound5":
        sound5.play()
        print("s5")
    case "sound6":
        sound6.play()
        print("s6")
    case "sound7":
        sound7.play()
        print("s7")
    case "sound8":
        sound8.play()
        print("s8")
    case "sound9":
        sound9.play()
        print("s9")
    case "sound10":
        sound10.play()
        print("s10")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

in your custom cell delete tap gesture for centerImageView:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

lazy var centerImageView: UIImageView = {
    var img = UIImageView()
    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    img.clipsToBounds = true
    img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return img
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    contentView.addSubview(centerImageView)
    centerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    centerImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    centerImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    centerImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

**FOR SYSTEM SOUNDS:**

replace your var declaration like this:

```
var sound1: SystemSoundID = 1016
var sound2: SystemSoundID = 1322
var sound3: SystemSoundID = 1110
var sound4: SystemSoundID = 1070
var sound5: SystemSoundID = 1109
var sound6: SystemSoundID = 1117
var sound7: SystemSoundID = 1106
var sound8: SystemSoundID = 1118
var sound9: SystemSoundID = 1256
var sound10: SystemSoundID = 1116
```

deleting setting up sound 1, 2 etc. and replace the switch case in didSelectItemAt with this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let s = sounds[indexPath.item]
    switch s {
    case "sound1":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (sound1)
        print("s1")
    case "sound2":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound2)
        print("s2")
    case "sound3":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound3)
        print("s3")
    case "sound4":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound4)
        print("s4")
    case "sound5":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound5)
        print("s5")
    case "sound6":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound6)
        print("s6")
    case "sound7":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound7)
        print("s7")
    case "sound8":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound8)
        print("s8")
    case "sound9":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound9)
        print("s9")
    case "sound10":
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound10)
        print("s10")
    default:
        break
    }
  }
}
```

this is not the best way but it work fine, it will make you understand how it works and help you to learn

Comment: this is madness! This is poetry! What a good explanation! I got it all working but most important you really took the time to explain the steps which make me learn about how it all works. Thank you, thank you very much! One day I hope to be as good to help other people out on StackOverflow. Have a great weekend my Italian friend, greetings from the Netherlands! Ciao

Comment: @DeDeSchurk Happy coding my friend, I am sure you will become a very good programmer :) Have a great WE too!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is implementation of the `didSelectItemAt` function. You can implement like so by putting with your other collection view functions like `cellForItemAt`. Then, make sure the required sound is closely linked with your data source. Meaning you can access the sound you want via `indexPath.item`, which is a way of identifying the specific cell that got tapped.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Use indexPath.item to determine what sound to play
}
```